# Combine background css using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, background

Anyone know how to add css background without replacing the previous background with js?

for example,

```
<div style = "background: url (image.png)"> </ div>
```

after added

```
<div style = "background: url (image2.png), url (image.png)"> </ div>
```

Comment: Do you want to override the previous image with new one?

Comment: You cant have two backgrounds at once.

Comment: @JosanIracheta You can, with CSS3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Javascript solution:

```js
var backgroundStyle = document.querySelector("#container").style.background;

document.querySelector("#container").style.background = backgroundStyle + ", url('http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg')";
```

```html
<div style = "background: url('http://www.brightlinkprep.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/sample.jpg')" id="container" >
</div>
```

You can verify it using the Developer Tools / FireBug.

Comment: @Alan Note that the URL should be in quotes in your style.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of CSS classes and switch between classes when required.

```
.class_one {
    background: url (image.png);
}

.class_two {
    background: url (image2.png), url (image.png);
}
```

Comment: I need a background "image2.png" that can be changed with javascript

Comment: @Alan, is there any issues with the above solution?

Comment: May be @Gael's answer is you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the background value, and append another *url(img_url)*

```
var my_div= document.querySelector("my_div");
if( my_div.style.background == "" )
 my_div.style.background= "url(image.png)";
else
 my_div.style.background+= ",url(image2.png)";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds

Comment: is there a way to add, without get previous background?

Comment: You should have to test is already a background, to know if you need to add a comma.

Comment: I would suggest you to use classes as on the first answer. It's cleaner.